# Changing background color of gedit's whitespace highlighting

Tags: gedit

I've used NEdit since about 2003. NEdit's whitespace highlighting is subtle and I prefer it to the dot other editors put in whitespace. NEdit's background normally is light grey and whitespace is rendered as white without a dot (and tabs in a darker gray).

However, NEdit doesn't support UTF-8 encoding, so I don't intend to use NEdit for much longer. I've (reluctantly) determined that gedit is the presently available editor that is closest to what I want.

I am trying to replicate NEdit's look in gedit without success. I can change the style of the spaces shown with the "Draw Spaces" plugin by adding the following to the gedit style file:

```
<style name="draw-spaces" foreground="color"/>
```

The `foreground` property only changes the color of the dot. There does not appear to be a corresponding `background` property to change the background. I thought if I made `foreground` and `background` the same color then I could replicate NEdit's look.

How can I change the background color of the whitespace highlighting in gedit without also changing the background color of the remainder of the text?